# Cannot Change Images after publishing my project Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel

I have published my Laravel Project on Hostgator but when iam tring to edit or change the default image it give me error :

> NotWritableException Can't write image data to path
>   (/home3/abuali1985/public_html/orbitgit_app/public/orbitgit_app/uploads/user_images/fnM9Ds3RavZTa1irb7fqh0sX9ObaP11v7jYejITI.jpeg)

```
/home3/abuali1985/public_html/orbitgit_app/vendor/intervention/image/src/Intervention/Image/Image.php
 */
public function save($path = null, $quality = null, $format = null)
{
    $path = is_null($path) ? $this->basePath() : $path;

    if (is_null($path)) {
        throw new NotWritableException(
            "Can't write to undefined path."
        );
    }

    if ($format === null) {
        $format = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    }

    $data = $this->encode($format, $quality);
    $saved = @file_put_contents($path, $data);

    if ($saved === false) {
        throw new NotWritableException(
            "Can't write image data to path ({$path})"
        );
    }

    // set new file info
    $this->setFileInfoFromPath($path);

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Runs a given filter on current image
 *
 * @param  FiltersFilterInterface $filter
 * @return \Intervention\Image\Image
```

Can you help me please ?

file systems file code :

```
 <?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Filesystem Disk
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the default filesystem disk that should be used
    | by the framework. The "local" disk, as well as a variety of cloud
    | based disks are available to your application. Just store away!
    |
    */

    'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'local'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Cloud Filesystem Disk
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Many applications store files both locally and in the cloud. For this
    | reason, you may specify a default "cloud" driver here. This driver
    | will be bound as the Cloud disk implementation in the container.
    |
    */

    'cloud' => env('FILESYSTEM_CLOUD', 's3'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Filesystem Disks
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure as many filesystem "disks" as you wish, and you
    | may even configure multiple disks of the same driver. Defaults have
    | been setup for each driver as an example of the required options.
    |
    | Supported Drivers: "local", "ftp", "sftp", "s3", "rackspace"
    |
    */

    'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
        'public_uploads' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => public_path('uploads'),

        ],
        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
        ],

    ],

];
```

the usercontroller code :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Branch;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public  function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware(['permission:read_users'])->only('index');
        $this->middleware(['permission:create_users'])->only('create');
        $this->middleware(['permission:update_users'])->only('edit');
        $this->middleware(['permission:delete_users'])->only('destroy');
    }
    public function index(Request $request)
    {

        $users=User::whereRoleIs('admin')->where(function ($q) use ($request){
            return $q->when($request->search, function ($query) use ($request){
                return $query->where('first_name', 'like' , '%' . $request->search .'%')
                    ->orWhere('last_name', 'like' , '%' . $request->search . '%');
            }) ;
        })->latest()->paginate(5);
        $branches = Branch::all();
        return view('users.index',compact('users','branches'));
    }


    public function create()
    {
        $branches = Branch::all();
        return view('users.create',compact('branches'));
    }


    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'first_name'=>'required',
            'last_name'=>'required',
            'email'=>'required|unique:users',
            'image'=>'image',
            'branch_id'=>'required',
            'password'=>'required|confirmed',
            'permissions'=>'required|min:1',
            'mobile'=>'required|min:9',

        ]);
        $request_data = $request->except(['password','password_confirmation','permissions','image']);
        $request_data['password'] = bcrypt($request->password);

        if ($request->image)
        {
            Image::make($request->image)->resize(300,null,function($constraint){
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
            })->save(public_path('orbitgit_app/uploads/user_images/' . $request->image->hashName()));

            $request_data['image'] = $request->image->hashName();
        }



        $user = User::create($request_data);
        $user->attachRole('admin');
        $user->syncPermissions($request->permissions);

        session()->flash('success',__('site.added_successfully'));
        return redirect()->route('users.index');
    }





    public function edit(User $user)
    {
        $branches = Branch::all();
        return view('users.edit', compact('user','branches'));
    }


    public function update(Request $request, User $user)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'first_name'=>'required',
            'last_name'=>'required',
            'email'=>['required',Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id)],
            'image'=>'image',
            'permissions'=>'required|min:1',
            'mobile'=>'required|min:9',

        ]);
        $request_data = $request->except(['permissions','image']);

        if ($request->image)
        {
            if($user->image != 'default.png'){
                Storage::disk('public_uploads')->delete('/user_images/' . $user->image);

            }

            Image::make($request->image)->resize(300,null,function($constraint){
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
            })->save(public_path('orbitgit_app/uploads/user_images/' . $request->image->hashName()));

            $request_data['image'] = $request->image->hashName();
        }


        $user->update($request_data);
        $user->syncPermissions($request->permissions);
        session()->flash('success',__('site.updated_successfully'));
        return redirect()->route('users.index');
    }


    public function destroy(User $user)
    {
        if ($user->image != 'default.png'){
            Storage::disk('public_uploads')->delete('/user_images/' . $user->image);
        }
        $user->delete();
        session()->flash('success',__('site.deleted_successfully'));
        return redirect()->route('users.index');
    }
}
```

Comment: do you use a form with image ? it's a ftp issue ? it's the upload part of form ? it's the move file ? do you have a code with the line that generates the error ?

Comment: i edited my post with the code of error page and i said it is working very good in the localhost but after i published it i created two folders (orbitgit) for public folder content and (orbitgit_app) for all project files without the public folder

Comment: @MohamadSalama could you plz share your `filesystems.php` config file and your controller code responsible for image storage

Comment: @ Foued MOUSSI Done

Answer (score 0):

It's likely a permissions issue where your SSH user can manipulate the `/home3/abuali1985/public_html/orbitgit_app/public/orbitgit_app/uploads/` folder and it's underlying images but the server is running your app with a different user and it doesn't have the necessary permissions.

SSH to that folder and ensure the correct user has permission with `chmod -R 775` or the highest necessary permissions required for your app to function correctly on the production server.

Comment: done but i got same error but upload folder now is not in orbitgit_app folder it moved with public folder into orbitgit folder